# RadioSelect with image

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible for Pmw.RadioSelect's buttons to have an icon next to the text? Supposing we have a few buttons added in a Frame, each one of them has different icon on left or right side of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add images to RadioButton widgets by doing this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

radiobtn = Radiobutton(root)

# Image location (add "/" not "\")
img = PhotoImage(file="C:/path to image/image.png") 

# Applying image to the Radiobutton
radiobtn.config(image=img)

# Display Radiobutton
radiobtn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Check out [Radiobutton documentation](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm) for more info.